# Is pandas.dataframe.pivot_table() a better solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

The code below allows me to determine what the most common main dish and the most common method of preparation for the most common main dish, for each US Region.  It uses data obtained from 'thanksgiving-2015-poll-data.csv' which can be found here https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/thanksgiving-2015.  I believe that a pivot_table might offer a more efficient method of getting the same information, but I can figure out how to do so.  Can anyone offer any insight?  Here's the code I used to get this information which works but I feel is not the best (fastest) method for doing so.

```
    import pandas as pd

    data = pd.read_csv('thanksgiving-2015-poll-data.csv', encoding="Latin-1")
    regions = data['US Region'].value_counts().keys()
    main_dish = data['What is typically the main dish at your Thanksgiving dinner?']
    main_dish_prep = data['How is the main dish typically cooked?']
    regional_entire_meal_data_rows = []

    for region in regions:
        is_in_region = data['US Region'] == region
        most_common_regional_dish = main_dish[is_in_region].value_counts().keys().tolist()[0]
        is_region_and_most_common_dish = (is_in_region) & (main_dish == most_common_regional_dish)
        most_common_regional_dish_prep_type = main_dish_prep[is_region_and_most_common_dish].value_counts().keys().tolist()[0]
        regional_entire_meal_data_rows.append((region, most_common_regional_dish, most_common_regional_dish_prep_type))

    labels = ['US Region', 'Most Common Main Dish', 'Most Common Prep Type for Main Dish']
    regional_main_dish_data = pd.DataFrame(regional_entire_meal_data_rows, columns=labels)

    full_meal_message = '''\n\nThe table below shows a breakdown of the most common 
    full Thanksgiving meal broken down by region.\n'''
    print(full_meal_message)
    print(regional_main_dish_data)
```

Comment: How long does it take to run?  What's your target runtime?

Comment: @John Total runtime is 0.04688453674316406 seconds.  Don't have a specific target, just want to challenge my self to get it as fast as possible.  I'd like to see if a pivot_table will speed things up a bit, not sure how to do so.

Comment: In that case the question belongs here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross posted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/169646/127098